# When I ping Internet addresses like yahoo or Google, I get 2 reply packets and 2 lost packets

Tags: networking, ping

I have Airtel broadband and a Tata broadband connection. i have around 50 PCs connecting through an airtel broadband connection.

Both are dsl connections with my phone line going into dsl modems and an Ethernet cable going from dsl modem directly into a switch. Currently, only airtel connection is connected with static IP on my private lan and using the airtel ISP DNS servers as DNS IP address and the default gateway is 192.168.1.1 (IP add. of the dsl modem). All PCs are connected in a work group.

When in full use, my users complain of certain web pages are not opening. When I ping Internet addresses like Yahoo or Google I get 2 reply packets and 2 lost packets. I suspect that a single broadband connection is not able to sustain 50 simultaneous downloads/browsing.

Is there any device which connect to both DSL and make one line so that its give me high speed simultaneous browsing. Help needed urgently. Thank you all to those who reply.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue, some packets are being sent to a gateway that is unreachable. Since you said one of your connections is down, that's probably the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Packet loss tells me that something is malfunctioning somewhere, likely a switch or the modem itself.  Depending on what you're doing, a DSL connection should be adequate for 50 users just surfing the Web: I have several clients on standard business class DSL connections (5Mbps down, ~800Kbps up) with ~100 users using the Internet for standard Web surfing and email and performance is fine.

I do find that I regularly swap out DSL modems, regardless of manufacturer: they just seem to be cheaply made, get pretty hot, and die eventually.  Might be worthwhile as a quick test to swap in another DSL modem.

If you're a heavy Internet user (lots of downloading/uploading of large files, etc.) and with two DSL connections, I'd recommend getting an edge router that can do load balancing/failover and possibly Quality of Service (QoS): [Netgate](http://www.netgate.com/) sells ALIX kits with pfSense (Open Source) firewall, which has "enterprise" features for ~$200 USD.  Best bang for the buck for a firewall I've seen.  With that configuration, you can even setup policy-based routing to route certain traffic out one connection primarily (say, core server services like email, DNS, etc. get routed out through DSL #1, web surfing out #2), while failing over when it's down.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be issue with either your [lan switch] or [dsl modem].
packets are getting dropped. so check it out.

well for bonding two internet connection you can use linux and have a web accelerator application which will cache dns queries.
these link will clear all your doubts (i suppose)
[Is it possible to merge multiple internet connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67096/is-it-possible-to-merge-multiple-internet-connections)

Answer (score 0):

The two received, two dropped pattern is suspicious.  Does it continue if you ping for a longer period of time (ping -t www.google.com)?  What happens during off hours when you don't have a large user load?

Do a trace-route to a web site (i.e. tracert www.google.com), then do multiple pings to each hop along the way.  This should help you narrow down where your trouble begins.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 50% packet loss, this identifies a local network issue. To confirm whether the issue is being caused at the core level by either the DSL modem or a local switch, disconnect all other systems from the network, only connecting a single device to the internet. Confirm whether the problem still exists, if it does, replace one piece of hardware at a time to identify the issue.

If the issue resolves itself with a single device connected, another device on the network may be transmitting a high volume of information in a particular sequence which may be causing the packet loss pattern that you're seeing. Inspect each additional PC to identify the cause in this case. 50% packet loss in general identifies a network issue.