# I'm trying to Bond Two Internet uplink for Increased VPN Speed, but no luck

Tags: networking, bonding

I'm trying to Bond Two Internet uplink for Increased VPN Speed under this guide:
[How to Bond Two (Multiple) Internet Connections for Increased Speed and Failover](https://serverfault.com/questions/977589/how-to-bond-two-multiple-internet-connections-for-increased-speed-and-failover)

But I have some problems:

I've been working on it for days and it never works.

First of all, My network topology: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgbNS.png

In my scenario, please have a look of my config:

#### Client side:

vim /etc/network/interface

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
  address 192.168.50.254
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.50.1
  post-up /usr/local/bin/vpn-start
  pre-down /usr/local/bin/vpn-stop
```

Is my routing set up right in vpn-start?

```
# vim /usr/local/bin/vpn-start
#!/bin/bash
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/tap0.conf
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/tap1.conf
ip link add bond0 type bond
ip addr add 10.80.0.2/30 dev bond0

ip link set tap0 master bond0
ip link set tap1 master bond0
ip link set bond0 up mtu 1440
ip route add 192.168.50.0/24 via 10.80.0.1  <--Is this right?
```

How about the firewall config?

```
version 6

lan="ens160"
vpn="bond+"

interface "${lan}" lan
  policy accept

interface "${vpn}" vpn
  policy accept

router vpn2lan inface "${vpn}" outface "${lan}"
  policy accept
```

#### Server side:

tap0.conf:

```
# disable encryption, traffic continues unencrypted anyways
auth none
cipher none
dev tap0
mode p2p
port 1194
local 192.168.0.250   <-- Local ip or public ip?
proto udp
log /var/log/tap0.log
verb 3
ping 2
ping-restart 10
persist-tun
compress lz4-v2
daemon
```

Firewall config:

```
version 6
server_vpn_ports="udp/1194-1195"
client_vpn_ports="default"
snat4 to 192.168.0.250 outface ens33 dst not 192.168.0.250  <-- What does this mean? local ip or public ip?
interface ens33 web
  protection strong
  server ssh accept
  server vpn accept
  # more servers here as per your needs
  client all accept
interface bond0 vpn
  policy accept
router4 web2vpn inface ens33 outface bond0 dst 192.168.50.0/24,10.80.0.2  <--Is this right?
  client all accept
```

After I did all the setup, the link appeared to be established:

#### Client side:

```
root@ubcloud:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
```

Client tap1.log:

```
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 ******* WARNING *******: All encryption and authentication features disabled -- All data will be tunnelled as clear text and will not be protected against man-in-the-middle changes. PLEASE DO RECONSIDER THIS CONFIGURATION!
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tap1
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]118.152.247.193:1195
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET]192.168.50.254:1195
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]118.152.247.193:1195
Sat Aug  1 06:44:39 2020 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]118.152.247.193:1195
Sat Aug  1 06:44:41 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

ping tunnel ip from client:

```
root@ubcloud:~# ping 10.80.0.2
PING 10.80.0.2 (10.80.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.80.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 10.80.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
64 bytes from 10.80.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
^C
--- 10.80.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2050ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.019/0.023/0.026/0.005 ms
root@ubcloud:~# ping 10.80.0.1
PING 10.80.0.1 (10.80.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.80.0.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.80.0.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.80.0.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

#### Server side:

```
root@ubcloud:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: tap0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: a6:fa:e9:55:79:2c
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: tap1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: ae:b9:4a:50:b0:dc
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Server tap0.log:

```
root@ubcloud:~# cat /var/log/tap0.log
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 30 2019
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 ******* WARNING *******: All encryption and authentication features disabled -- All data will be tunnelled as clear text and will not be protected against man-in-the-middle changes. PLEASE DO RECONSIDER THIS CONFIGURATION!
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]192.168.0.250:1194
Sat Aug  1 06:43:27 2020 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
Sat Aug  1 06:43:30 2020 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.227.224.139:1194
Sat Aug  1 06:43:30 2020 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sat Aug  1 06:43:30 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

ping tunnel ip from server:

```
root@ubcloud:~# ping 10.80.0.1
PING 10.80.0.1 (10.80.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.80.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 10.80.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
^C
--- 10.80.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1030ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.048/0.053/0.059/0.009 ms
root@ubcloud:~# ping 10.80.0.2
PING 10.80.0.2 (10.80.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.80.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.80.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.80.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Any ideas what did I do wrong?
How do I set up the routing on the client so that all the traffic in the LAN Let the traffic in the LAN go out from the server through the tunnel?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider upgrading the VPN infrastructure rather than bond as a work-around.

2 bonded VPN links are never going to be as good as a dedicated VPN connection with the bandwidth that you require in a single link.

Answer (score 0):

From a [similar question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60615/how-can-i-accomplish-vpn-across-dual-wan-connections) asked on our sister site, Network Engineering:

> "Bonding" the links together sounds like a great idea on paper, but in
> practice it doesn't work very well. If you try to split a single
> connection between two links, you will get out of order packets,
> especially on two different networks, This will significantly lower
> your throughput. You'd be better off using only one link.
>
> VPN software for remote users isn't sophisticated enough to make two
> VPN connections and then make routing decisions to use the best path.
> I'm unaware of any such product. You would probably have to create
> something custom, but I doubt it would be worth the effort.